# Как избавиться от такого безобразия?

Tags: ооп, style-guide, code-style, php

Не вполне освоился с ООП, поэтому временами рождается такое:

```
function foo( $bar ) {
    $this->biz( $this->baz( $bar ) );
}
```

Подскажите, как написать код правильнее. Двойное **$this** не радует. Полагаю, что в итоге это должно выглядеть как-то так:

```
function foo( $bar ) {
    $this->biz->baz( $bar );
}
```

Comment: а что тебе не нравится?)

Comment: Какой Вам нужен результат?

Comment: Хотя бы повторы $this. Мне кажется, одного раза вполне достаточно.

Comment: @exec эстетически радующий

Comment: > Мне кажется, одного раза вполне
> достаточно.

В этом случае нужно переписывать исходники пэхопэ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если функция biz будет возвращать $this тогда второй $this не нужен, например:

```
function foo( $bar ) {
    $this->biz()->baz( $bar ) ;
}

function biz()   {
   . . . 
   return $this;
}
```

Comment: fluent syntax

Answer (score 0):

Непонятно что делает функция biz и что делает функция baz.

Но я бы предложил так:

```
function foo( $bar ) {
    $this->biz($bar);
}
fucntion biz($bar){
    $this->baz($bar)
}
```

Очень зависит от того, что именно вам требуется. 
Конечно $this(или результаты его методов/значения свойств) передавать в качестве параметра чаще всего странно.